# Is there any vs code shortcut to go press enter and go to next line while I am inside a code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When I am using vs code say I want to write

```
1. print("Hello World")
2.
```

What happens is when I complete writing `print("` it automatically adds `")` which is amazing and saves a lot of time. But the problem is, at the end of writing the code, my blinking cursor is stuck in the middle like this:

```
1. print("Hello World|")
2.
```

Now if I press enter to go to the next line, it will become like this:

```
1. print("Hello World
2. |")
3.
```

So in order to go to the next line, I have to click click twice or more on the right arrow depending on the line of code, and then press enter. This makes the whole thing very annoying and time-consuming. **But I am damn sure there's a way out**. At least all the youtube videos I see, they don't do that. I just don't know how to do it. Please help me if you know how to get over this problem.

Comment: They probably press `End` followed by `Enter`, the characters after the cursor `")` are virtual characters until you walk over them with the arrow key or `End` key. These characters are removed if you use `Backspace` and remove the opening character.

Comment: It is working! But can I assign custom key to End key?

Comment: Update: The question has been precisely answered by @Costa

Comment: `Insert Line Below`: I learn every day a new thing for VSC, now I try to remember this command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem should be solved with Shift + Enter

Edit: If it doesn't work for you, check the keybind that is set. Go to File, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts and search for Insert Line Below. You can set up a keybind there and use that instead.

Comment: Shift + Enter is opening python in terminal

Comment: I edited the answer for you, maybe that works for you!

Comment: `Insert Line Below` is Ctrl+Enter.  No need to rebind unless you want to.

Comment: In my Vs Code the Keyboard Shortcut was already set to `Ctrl + Enter` but Github Copilot was conflit that so I've changed to `Shift + Enter` Now It's working properly Thanks again @Costa

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + enter`
does work for me without any shortcut customization whatsoever.
I am using VS Code

Answer (score -1):

I am on Windows 11, and the instead of shift + enter, it is Control + Enter.